# $n$-player version of Zermelo's Theorem

Tags: game-theory

Zermelo's Theorem states that "Every finite zero-sum 2-player game is determined (one of the two players has a winning strategy)." I was wondering if anyone has investigated the generalization of this theorem to more than 2-player games. A proof, reference, or counterexample to this theorem for more than 2-players would be an answer that I am looking for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am no expert, but it seems to me that with at least three players things get messy.

Consider the following trivial game with players $A,B,C$: the first two moves of $A,B$ are irrelevant, and then $C$ chooses between two options where payoffs are $(1,-1,0)$ (i.e. $A$ wins) and $(-1,1,0)$ (i.e. $B$ wins), and the game ends there. Then, the fate of $A$ and $B$ depend on the decision by $C$, who has no particular incentive to choose either, so surely there is no hope for a winning strategy for anyone. Would that be a counterexample you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks! Your example helped.

Answer (score 3):

That is actually not what Zermelo has shown, ase explained [here](http://www.labri.fr/perso/gimbert/enseignement/enseirb/zermelo.pdf).

A winning strategy is not even defined for other games.

What is closely related to how many people (wrongly) believed Zermelo has shown such a thing is Kuhn's "algorithm": In games of [perfect information](http://www.gametheory.net/dictionary/PerfectInformation.html), one gets a [Nash equilibrium](http://www.gametheory.net/dictionary/NashEquilibrium.html) by [backward induction](http://www.gametheory.net/dictionary/BackwardInduction.html) (that also satisfies subgame perfection). One gets a unique Nash equilibrium this way, when no player is indifferent between any two plays.