# Classification of $n \times n$ matrix in which each two components differ in each row and column up to automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, permutations

Suppose, we define a class $A$ of  $n \times n$ matrix as follows: $$\text{In each Row }i, \text{for any} j,k\ (1 \leq j,k \leq n )\ a_{ij} \neq a_{ik} $$   $$\text{In each Column }l, \text{for any } p,q\ (1 \leq p,q \leq n )\ a_{pl} \neq a_{ql} $$ $$\text{Each component } a_{rs} \in \mathbb{N} \cap [1, n] $$

Two matrices $A$ and $B$ that both satisfy the above conditions(that is,  in each row and column,  no two components are the same) are isomorphic, if:

$$\text{There is a permutation } f: \{1,2,\ldots,n\} \to \{1,2,\ldots,n\}\text{ such that  for any } 1 \leq j,k \leq n, f(a_{jk}) = b_{jk}$$

My question is, given $n$, how many kinds of $n \times n$ matrices are there up to the defined isomorphism?

**Motivation**:Inspired by [Samuel Reid's question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354596/n-player-version-of-zermelos-theorem), I am trying to find a generalization of $n$-person zero sum sequential game of perfect information. A natural way to generalize the payoff set is to replace it by a partition of the set of all outcomes with exactly $n$ atoms. Each person has a complete strict order on those $n$ atoms. To avoid difficulty  in Feanor's answer, one way is to require that, for each atom of outcomes, there isn't a pair of players that assigns the same ranking to it. In the cases $n = 2,3$, there is only one kind of players' preference up to isomorphism. But What can we say in general.

Comment: After playing around a bit I would guess $(n-1)!(n-2)!\cdots 2!$

Comment: @SimonMarkett:Thank you for your comment. It seems to me, that according to your formula, when $n =3$, the answer is $2$. But I think it should be $1$.

Comment: Aren't the matrices $(123,231,312)$ and $(123,312,231)$ distinct?

Comment: @SimonMarkett: Ah,sorry. I unconsiously took the permutation of players into consideration. Could you please provide an answer?

Comment: Hmm... I don't have a smart solution and brute-forcing it is gonna be ugly. I just made an educated guess...therefore only a comment.

Comment: Such matrices are called latin squares (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square) and the number of them up to isomorphism is $(n-1)!$ times the number of reduced latin squares of size $n$.