# Optimal strategy for stochastic four-player chess

Tags: game-theory

For 2-player chess [Zermelo's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%27s_theorem_(game_theory)) states that there is either a winning strategy for one of the players or a way to force a draw for both players. However, this result does not extend to [four-player chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-player_chess). It is possible that no player can force a win and no player can force a draw in this game.

Let's modify the game by introducing non-determinism. Before every move, a player rolls a dice and skips their turn with some constant probability $p$. Placing your king under check is allowed because there is always a chance it will not be captured successfully, and winning requires that kings of all other players are captured. This way there is always a chance for any player to win at any point in game and therefore an incentive to choose the move maximizing their chance to win.

The question is, **is there an optimal strategy for every player in this game, maximizing their chance to win under assumption that every other player is trying to maximize their chance to win?**

There is a related question asking for an optimal strategy for deterministic N-player chess at [Is perfect play always possible in a game with perfect information and more than 2 players?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4417027/is-perfect-play-always-possible-in-a-game-with-perfect-information-and-more-than)

There is also a related algorithmic question about extending MiniMax algorithm to N-player games: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826451/extending-minimax-algorithm-for-multiple-opponents
However, it is not clear what happens if some players face choices which are equal for them but affect other players differently.

For background, more practical question I am interested in is whether it makes sense to search for optimal AI in tactical games like [The Battle for Wesnoth](https://www.wesnoth.org/) assuming fog of war is disabled so it is a game with perfect information. Stochastic chess described above seems to capture the essence of such tactical games.

There are similar ideas in game theory introducing forced non-determinism into player strategy like [Trembling hand perfect equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trembling_hand_perfect_equilibrium), but there are multiple ways to do it and I am rather interested in existence of optimal strategy for a game that has already non-deterministic rules.